# MSBingTranslator - trouble getting the access token for iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, token, microsoft-translator

Kind a hard time to execute the step 3 (which is to get an access token) in this tutorial:

http://wangpidong.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-use-new-bing-translator-api-with.html

How can I do that? I'm a beginner in iOS development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still cant follow the instruction in the link... but i found a site that help me get the access token i want : http://oauthdevconsole.cloudapp.net/PartialOAuth